React + Electron: How to switch context from a modal dialog button press
Currently, I am working on an application built with React + Electron. I am trying to swap from one context to another on a button press from within a popup dialog.
The UI Layout is as follows:
There is a sidebar that allows for navigation between different contexts.
There is a header that shows information about the current context.
There is the context component itself, with user-interactive subcomponents. Each context is defined in its own file.
Within one context component, named ‘Calibration’, I am trying to switch to another context component, ‘Run’, from a button press action, within a dialog, within the Calibration component, without clicking the corresponding button in the sidebar. In other words, clicking the button in the dialog box should perform the same action as clicking the ‘Run’ button in the sidebar.
I have tried using React Router to achieve this, but the result is that the Run context is nested within the Calibration context instead of swapping them. Here’s the JSX for the dialog box:
<DialogActions>
<Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button> // if cancel, just close the dialog
<Button onClick={runCalibration} autoFocus> // if OK, call runCalibration
{'Ok'}
</Button>
</DialogActions>

Here’s the runCalibration
const navigate = useNavigate()

…

const runCalibration = () => {
    if (selectedCalibMenu) {
      loadCalibrationPgm(selectedCalibMenu?.pgmname) // Load a selected calibration file
      navigate('@views/run/Run')    // Switch to the run screen -- This is the errant line! 
    }
    setDialogOpen(false)
}

How do I use React Router to switch a context, instead of nesting it inside of another? Is React Router even necessary for the behaviour I am looking for? I noticed that the sidebar switches context via React.Dispatch, so maybe that’s what I should really be looking into?

This post kind of has the exact opposite problem of your Staging-Ground post in that you removed too much detail and relevant information. We still need to see what and where the routes are being rendered, in order to help you navigate correctly and render the expected UI. Now we need a more complete [mcve]. I'd still suggest paring your other code down to a simpler example that still reproduces the routing/navigation issue you are trying to address.
